# Making solidify modifier inside shape conform to the outside shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Here's a cut section of the top of my bottle. I would rather like the inside edge to conform to the outside edge (as I drew on the right side). Is there a simple setting that allows this?

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I had already added the soiidify modifier and that's what it gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm lacking the information I'd need for more than an guess, and it should be taken to account that I have less experience using the solidify modifier than certain others. That said, the first things I'd check are that:

you've applied scale and rotation to the object, before applying the solidify modifier;

you have the origin of the bottle object located in the center of the bottle object; and

you've chosen the proper pivot point before applying the modifier.

Comment: Looks like applying scale and rotation to the object did the trick --thank you.

Comment: What does the pivot point have to do with applying the modifier?